# Data not coming in form when clicked in Edit button in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

The data that is passed to assignmentAudit.component.ts when `Edit` Button is clicked is :

```
onEdit(nas:any){
 console.log(nas);

 this.assignmentAudit.auditorGroupNo=nas.assignmentAudit[0].auditorGroup.groupDesc;
 this.assignmentAudit.assignmentDate=nas.assignmentAudit[0].auditorGroup.assignmentDate;
 this.assignmentAudit.id=nas.assignmentAudit[0].id;
 this.assignmentAudit.selectionNo=nas.selectionId;
 this.assignmentAudit.magNo=0;

}
```

The `console.log(nas);` data is:
[image]

I have the form which has two input field is :

```
<form name="form" #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid &&  onSubmit()" novalidate class="">
<div class="form-group row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <label for="auditorGroup">Auditor Group</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="auditorGroup" required [(ngModel)]="assignmentAudit.auditorGroupNo" name="auditorGroup"
      #auditorGroup="ngModel"
      [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': f.submitted && auditorGroup.invalid }"
      required
      >
      <option *ngFor="let title of auditorgroups" [value]="title.auditorGroupId">{{title.groupDesc}}</option>
      </select>
      <div *ngIf="f.submitted && auditorGroup.invalid" class="invalid-input">
         <div *ngIf="auditorGroup.errors?.required">Auditor Group is required</div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="assignmentDate">Assignment Date</label>
         <input type="date" id="assignmentDate"  class="form-control" name="assignmentDate" placeholder="Please enter the Assignment Date" [(ngModel)]="assignmentAudit.assignmentDate" #assignmentDate="ngModel"
         [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': f.submitted && assignmentDate.invalid }"
         required />
         <div *ngIf="f.submitted && assignmentDate.invalid" class="invalid-input">
            <div *ngIf="assignmentDate.errors?.required">Assignment Date is required</div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<button type="submit" style="margin-bottom: 50px;" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The forms look simple as :

[image]

The action i need is :
[image]

I have binded the data using **[(ngModel)]="assignmentAudit.assignmentDate"** in form and when i put the value on after button click on onEdit() operation **this.assignmentAudit.assignmentDate=nas.assignmentAudit[0].auditorGroup.assignmentDate;** as it should be binded bidirectionally,the data is not showing automatically in form . What is the problem?

Comment: Are you able to create a StackBlitz that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Do you have just one component for this ?

Comment: yes i have single component

Comment: please post auditorgroups